# Foam to fill toilet mating surface gap

Tags: toilet

The front of my toilet is not closing the gap with a marble tile floor. I can't fix the floor. I used some shower membrane under (not visible) and some shims (visible). If I can stick a foam spray nozzle in between two shims, should I spray foam inside to form a shape that would reinforce the shimming?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut your shims so they do not stick out past the porcelain use some silicone to keep them from moving and make sure the toilet does not rock or move. Foam will not reinforce the shims. Use toilet shims.

Then fill the gap with 100% silicone caulk, white or beige to match the floor.

Comment: I just did all of that exactly. F-ed up the caulking job, should have used masking tape. Will try to scrape later